# Pass Data From asp.net application to SL application at different hosts

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, cookies, silverlight-3.0

I've got two web independent applications: ASP.NET www.site1.com and SL(3) app www.site2.com. How can i pass some data(id,strings)  from asp.net to SL app. I was thinking about cookie, but I can't write cookies to any site. So is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using query strings,May be this will helpfull:

www.site1.com/yourData?id=ID&anyString=YourValue

Now , try loading the same valued in you SL3 Apps:

```
string ID= this.NavigationContext.QueryString[ "ID" ];   
string YourValue= this.NavigationContext.QueryString[ "YourValue" ];
```

Comment: it's some security info such as account to edit, so I can't pass it through uri. Thanks for answer

Comment: The links for encrypting your Data:
http://riawebsoft.ru/Silverlight/Rsa/TestEnglish.aspx

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878312/silverlight-encrypting-username-and-password-for-web-service